# Shuting down a motor using a limiting switch without using any microcontroller

Tags: motor-controller

I am designing a winch for carrying loads from a hole. I managed to put a boyer for alarm when the controller is not careful but I need a system to stop the motor from pulling when the bucket pass a certain distance from that boyer

I am using a three-phase motor, I need to use a limiting switch to stop the motor
[image: This is how it looks and how it should be]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*stop the motor*" ? If the supply is simply cut, will he bucket fall down into the hole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Use a three phase contactor (380/240/110V coil) to power the motor. The coil in the diagram represents the contactor coil.

Use the normally closed contacts of the limit switch. When the bucket hits the limit switch, it opens and shuts off the motor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how, using relay logic.

[image]

The thermal overload trip contact is not shown.

The power circuit is also not shown.